# lower bound on matrix norm inequality of sum

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

The question is simple: 
can we say this?

$\|A\|-\|B\|<\|A+B\|$

for any norm you like.

Comment: It fails when $B=0$, regardless of norm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in general you only have $\le$ and not $<$. The triangle inequality gives
$$
\|A\|=\|A+B-B\|\leq \|A+B\|+\|B\|.
$$
I leave it to you to find an example where equality holds.